# Autocomplete tagging with additional input data

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tags

You all know one dimensional, autocomplete tagging from Stackoverflows' input field for tags.
Now have a look at this: http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/#demo : For given facets (country, account, ...) you can additionally enter custom information. Unfortunately the list of facets is static and I cannot add new facets "on-the-fly" while typing in  the  input field.
Does anyone know a solution for a quasi two dimensional autocomplete tag/facet form where the tags/facets are variable and autocompleted as the additional information?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should check http://podio.github.com/jquery-mentions-input/. It allows you to autocomplete based on a triggerChar. It might be possible to use it multiple times on a textarea?!

Edit: This one is slightly better and accepts multiple trigger chars.
https://github.com/dtime/jquery-mentions-input

Edit: I found that I like this version the most:
http://daniel-zahariev.github.com/jquery-textntags/